# CMAKE error with Opencv in a workflow (github actions)

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, github-actions

I have a workflow on Github actions that is building on my macbook x64. It was working well until I formatted it and reinstalled it.
My last task which use maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0 is failing with this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelRelease'.
> /actions-runner/_work/app/CMakeLists.txt : C/C++ release|armeabi-v7a : CMake Error at /actions-runner/_work/app/CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
    By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
    asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
    CMake did not find one.
  
    Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
    of the following names:
  
      OpenCVConfig.cmake
      opencv-config.cmake
  
    Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
    "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
    provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
    installed.
```

I know the issue is on my machine as it was ok before (and not the code). I tried to install cmake and opencv on my machine but nothing changed. Do you have any idea of what I can do ?

Comment: "I tried to install cmake and opencv on my machine but nothing changed." - Since CMake claims the opposite (it cannot find OpenCV), you probably need to be a bit more detailed about your OpenCV installation. Does your installation have `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file, which is noted in the error message? Have you used system-wide installation, or give it custom installation prefix?

Comment: I did brew install opencv in the root of my mac and also used cmake gui to configure and generate a build. I have multiple OpenCVConfig.cmake in the opencv folder (in /install and /build).